# HDD works at one laptop but doesn't on another

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd, connector

Th situation is as follows:

- Laptop Dell 14z has Win 8.1 and OSZ Vector 128GB SSD HDD. At one moment is started installing updates (Win 8.1), suddenly rebooted and couldn't boot Win successfully. Things happen in the following way:
  1) PC boots to Windows booting logo 
  2) It runs for about 1,5-2 mins
  3) Then it shows a blue screen saying

> :( Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We're just
>   collecting some error info and then we'll restart

4) Then it restarts into a black (pre-boot like) screen saying

> Intel UNDI PXE 2.0 (build 083) 
>   
> ...
>   
>  For Atheros PCIE Ethernet
>   
>  Controller v2.0.2.7(01/10/12) Check cable connection!
>   
> PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM

LAN option is set to the latest in the BIOS bot order. So looks like it doesn't find the HDD - and right, the BIOS doesn't show the HDD for some time.

**However...**

I've taken the HDD out and put it into to another PC (Dell m301z) - it did boot fine!
Then I've taken the HDD back - it doesn't boot.

I've supposed I could have broken the connector between HDD and motherboard somehow, so have bought a new one.

I've taken out another drive (non-SSD) from the Dell m301z and put it into Dell 14z (aka "the non-booting laptop") - *it works fine*, boots into Ubuntu. Just fine!
I've tried this HDD on this laptop with both old and new HDD adapters - both are fine.

---

Any ideas?

Comment: You used the same exact adapter?

Comment: After another reboot (just now) it has thrown a blue screen with "Your PC couldn't start properly" error and error code 0xc000001, then (after reboot) - INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE.

Comment: @Ramhound yes exactly the same model. I've even mixed them up which was old and which was new, that's why decided to test both with another HDD.

Comment: I didn't ask if they were the model.  I asked if they were the exact same adapter.

Comment: @Ramhound yes they are exactly the same.

Comment: I am still not sure you understand my question.  Are you using the same physical adapter when testing the HDD in both computers.

Comment: @Ramhound got it. No, I use different adapters as Dell m301z and 14z have different adapters. When I say "adapter", I mean this device: http://img2.parts-people.com/products/N2RPKa.JPG
So I use two units of device shown on the photo.

Comment: After booting from a Linux USB and running grparted, I see the following:
-- grparted says that /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 have i/o errors and are not accessible - but it says about them so sees their existence somehow
-- gparted sees the whole drive as an "unrecognized" partition table and "unallocated" space

Comment: Looks like tor SSD has had it... I don't really trust SSDs yet. Just as a memory stick can suddenly stop, an SSD seems to be just as unreliable.